# how to set position of datalabels for barplot in coreplot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

Hi right now am facing an issue with  datalables! while am trying to display them on barplots they are  getting printed somewhat far from them,but i need to print those lables on the edges of the barplots. Is there any way to set the position of the datalabels??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `CPBarPlot` class reference in Core-Plot API:

http://florent.clairambault.fr/downloads/iPhone/core-plot-doc/interface_c_p_bar_plot.html

> **barLabelOffset**
>
> Sets the offset of the value label above the bar.